# Websphere Application Server v8 can't connect to server process

Tags: java, websphere, rad, websphere-8

My WAS8 server refuses to start. I've restarted the server, cleaned it, removed all EARs, restarted RAD, restarted my computer, and even re-installed Websphere but the error remains. Any ideas, before I reinstall RAD?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any personal firewalls installed?

Answer (score 4):

A few things I would check:

- Making sure the ports are set correctly and not occupied
- If it's a secured profile, make sure the credentials are set correctly
- Try to start the server in cmdline `<WAS install dir/profiles/<profileName>/bin/startServer <serverName>`
- Try creating a new profile if none of the above works

Comment: not sure why the path got cut off, it was suppose to be <WAS install dir>/profiles/<profileName>/bin/startServer <serverName>

Answer (score 3):

open RAD as "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "Start server with a generated script" option.

Comment: This worked for me +1, but "Test Connection" fails and breakpoints in JSP pages don't work

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when eclipse is closed or system shuts down when WAS is in running state.

Resolution:
Run eclipse as Administrator then start the server it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check log in WebSphere Installed folder\AppServer\profiles\your custom profile\logs.

For me, it was showing systemlaunch.properties file was missing with a specific version. I had to copy that from other system. But you may update different version from same folder and rename the properties file and update the contents appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

admin mode for ibm products...

Comment: single-line solution should be in comment.

Comment: this should be added as  comment, not answer.

Comment: This isn't a sentence.